# Auth0 with Rails API using Knock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, auth0, rails-api

Using [this](https://medium.com/devtechtipstricks/build-a-simple-rails-api-server-auth0-jwt-authentication-react-from-scratch-in-30-minutes-or-257cbb2a939a) tutorial I have been able to set up my Rails API with knock, but authentication doesn't seem to be working when I provide the JWT.

Here is my Knock.rb

```
Knock.setup do |config|

  config.token_audience = -> { Rails.application.secrets.auth0_client_id }
  config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { Rails.application.secrets.auth0_client_secret }

end
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  def self.from_token_payload payload
    payload['sub']
  end
end
```

projects_controller.rb:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user

  # GET /projects
  def index
      @projects = Project.all

      json_response(@projects)
  end

...

end
```

I got the JWT with a POST request to https://my-auth0-site.auth0.com/oauth/token

In postman:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must add Bearer to token. Look at the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem without being able to make it work. At the end I changed to the method recommended by the official Auth0 documentation. It is really simple and works perfect.

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/rails/01-authorization

Hope it helps.

Comment: Apparently there is a problem with Knock library, but I did not have much time to investigate it.

Comment: While it is OK for an answer to contain links to reference material, the answer itself should at least contain a stand-alone solution to the problem.

Comment: Agreed with @Johan. But I want to add that you should also address the reason why OP's code didn't work so we can understand not just why something else is right but why the current approach isn't